# Query that will return multiple of two fields?

Tags: apex, soql

I want to write a query that will return multiply of two fields. Is it possible?

```
// Aggregate Query to collect Sum of all Combinations of Brand Name and Reporting Groups.           
    List<AggregateResult> arrAllDaysCRsResult = [SELECT Sum(Relative_Date_Calculated__c) totalRewards, Brand_Name__c, Reporting_Group__c, Contractor__c FROM Contractor_Rewards__c 
                                        WHERE Brand_Name_Calculated__c in:brandNameSet AND Contractor__c in:contactsMap.keyset() // AND Reporting_Group__c in:reportingGroupSet
                                        group by Brand_Name__c, Reporting_Group__c, Contractor__c ];
```

here is my soql query and i want `Relative_Date_Calculated__c* TRANS_AMT__c`

Comment: Please do not change your post so radically that it becomes a completely new question. Instead, accept the given answer and ask a new question, linking back to the old one for reference if it helps provide context.

Comment: Hey Adrian..!!
Thank you for Your suggestion, you have edited my question two times...Let me inform 1st and then edit it,so i can handle it on my own level.

Comment: Turning your question into a completely different question is a bit of an abuse of the system. If you do so again it will just get rolled back (again). If you want to make minor edits, that's fine. But please do not ask a completely different question here when there is already an answer which has been well received.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it is not possible to multiply fields in SOQL but would be glad to be wrong about that.

Workaround would be to create a formula field like `num1num2Multiple` which will multiply these two fields ( `Relative_Date_Calculated__c* TRANS_AMT__c`).

Now get this Formula field in SOQL.

```
SELECT num1num2Multiple FROM Contractor_Rewards__c
```

You can remove this field from pagelayout if you do not want to show it on UI

Comment: hello samir..!! Thank you for the reply but i didn't get what is num1 and num2??
Did you mean Relative_Date_Calculated__c*TRANS_AMT__c  OR  (Relative_Date_Calculated__c*TRANS_AMT__c)Multiple..
can you please clear my doubt..Thank you.

Comment: They are sample fields.Assume `num 1 is Relative_Date_Calculated__c and num 2 is TRANS_AMT__c and num1num2Multiple is Relative_Date_Calculated__c* TRANS_AMT__c`

Comment: It is giving me the error ,   Unknown error parsing query

Comment: Where are you getting an error? you need to create a formula field and use that field in your SOQL as explained in the answer

Comment: Relative_Date_Calculated__c is already my formula field and i cant change that field because that is use in my apex classes,so i have to change only in soql query.

Comment: You can not multiply two fields in the query

Comment: any other way,that i can use? 
Actually this is used in my class ,so what should i do??

Comment: You can reference your formula field `Relative_Date_Calculated__c ` in new formula field.No need to make changed in your code.

Comment: @Sonammittal - Please mark it as the answer if this help you so that others can benefit from this.